# Storing and Accessing Objects

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have created a class in Java that contains 4 attributes (an ID code, city, state, and color).

What I need to be able to do is organize the objects I create using this class in some sort of array, and then be able to return the attributes of a certain object based on searching its ID number.

What would be the best method for doing this?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not how SO works. We do not do your homework for you. We will, however, help you when you have made a legitimate attempt at solving the issue yourself and gotten stuck somewhere very specific. Don't worry about finding the best way at first, worry about finding your own way. And part of learning coding is learning the proper way to ask for help.

Comment: Also, take a look at my edits. I have removed sections that are completely irrelevant to your question. Instead of telling us about your code, show it. Same with any attempts you have made. No one cares how long you have been struggling. All that matters is what you learned in the process. And show, don't tell for a preference.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond, but comments like yours are the reason I'm struggling so much. I am not asking anyone to "do my homework for me." I have researched for hours to figure this out and this was my last effort. Literally created an account just to post this. Thanks again.

Comment: You misunderstand me. You talk about what you claim you did without showing a single line of code. I don't see any attempt at making an array or anything. Your talk is plenty flowery, but it lacks any kind of substance. We only work with substance here.